# Double linked list without class

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I am still learning python and have the following code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None

    def traverse(self):
        node = self
        while node is not None:
            print(node.val)
            node = node.next


def LinkedListCreator(non_linked_list):
    linked_list = []
    for element in non_linked_list:
        node = Node(element)
        if(len(linked_list)) > 0:
            linked_list[-1].next = node
        linked_list.append(node)
        if(len(linked_list)) > 1:
            prev_node = linked_list[-2]
            linked_list[-1].prev = prev_node
    linked_list[0].prev = linked_list[-1]
    linked_list[-1].next = linked_list[0]
    return linked_list

abc = [1, 2, 3]
deg = LinkedListCreator(abc)

deg[0].traverse()
```

Now, given that this is a doubly linked list (but not really, since the list itself is not a class), how do I traverse it without going into an endless loop? The obvious choice would be to save the first element and stop the iteration when it reaches it again.
Is this also a correct implementation of a doubly linked list with a function, or should linked lists strictly be implemented as a class with their own class methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future I'd suggest posting this sort of question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

With respect to:

> how do I traverse it without going into an endless loop? The obvious choice would be to save the first element and stop the iteration when it reaches it again.

I'd do:

```
class Node:
    …

    def iter_vals(self):
        yield self.val
        node = self.next
        while node is not self:
            yield node.val
            node = node.next
```

I `yield` elements so the caller can decide what they want to do with them, rather than always printing them.  There are various ways of arranging this `while` loop, but none seems particularly better, e.g:

```
    def iter_vals(self):
        node = self
        while True:
            yield node.val
            node = node.next
            if node is self:
                break
```

would also work, but seems less clear.  With respect to your second question:

> Is this also a correct implementation of a doubly linked list with a function, or should linked lists strictly be implemented as a class with their own class methods?

I've not run your code, but it looks about right.  Whether it's worth creating a whole separate class for it depends on various engineering tradeoffs that you've not given any information about.  For example:

- what makes more sense to the callers
- does it need to hold any more state
- how are you going to be testing
- what other methods will you want to package with it

one thing I'd suggest would be naming conventions…  as you can see from how your code was colored, only class/type names tend to be CamelCased while other identifiers are lowercase.  I'd therefore name your `LinkedListCreator` something like `create_linked_list`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to "save" the first element, as that is what your *self* Variable already does. The minimal addition to make your code work would be to break if the nodes sucessor equals the traversing node:

```
    def traverse(self):
        node = self
        while node is not None:
            print(node.val)
            node = node.next
            if node == self:
                break
```

or equally but maybe a bit more intuitive to read:

```
    def traverse(self):
        node = self
        while node is not None:
            print(node.val)
            if node.next == self:
                break
            node = node.next
```